# Cucumber test to ensure that an error message is attached to a particular form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Using Devise and Cucumber, and I've got the following code for scenarios where the user tries to signup without a password:

```
Then /^I should see a missing password message$/ do
  page.should have_content "Password can't be blank"
end
```

This is fine when displaying errors at the top of the form, but I have now switched to inline messages, which means that the attribute name is no longer referenced in it's associated error message, so I need to change my code to this:

```
Then /^I should see a missing password message$/ do
  page.should have_content "can't be blank"
end
```

Now my features pass, but I'm not 100% happy with this solution. I would feel better if I could also test that this message is attached to the empty password_field, and not just positioned somewhere on the page. I was wondering if there was a way to say something like this:

```
Then /^I should see a missing password message$/ do
  password_field.should have_content "can't be blank"
end
```

I'm quite new to cucumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out finding and scoping in the capybara docs: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/#finding

```
find('#password').should have_content("can't be blank")
```